# How to mock XMLHTTPRequest in typescript for unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, webpack, jasmine

I have this code in my src file and I want to write unit test for this. I am using karma-webpack in angular 4 application. Please suggest

```
public static load(jsonFile: string): Promise<boolean> {
console.log('calling loadinstance');
return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
  const xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  xobj.open('GET', jsonFile, true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = () => {
    const readyOK = 4;
    const responseOK = 200;
    if (xobj.readyState === readyOK) {
      if (xobj.status === responseOK) {
        ConfigLoader.data = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText);
        resolve(true);
      }
      else {
        reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${xobj.status}`);
      }
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Quiet simple use a spyOn.

```
it('Your Service', inject([YourService], (YourService: yourService) => {
  spyOn(yourService, 'load').and.returnValue(loadedJSON);
```

Comment: I am unit testing load method itself. Is it okay to spy the same method which we are testing?

Comment: Why would you test the service itself if you already know the result of it?
Service are not meant to be tested cause you not test the real service but a fake. So the respond is fake to. You test your component and HTML.

Comment: @Swoox `Service are not meant to be tested cause you not test the real service but a fake.` This is incorrect. Services can certainly have nontrivial logic, which is what needs testing. One may need to translate either the method parameters or an API response, swallow or force errors, and so on.

Comment: @MadanMohanKannojiya There's nothing wrong with spying on it, per se, but it's not likely to be useful.  General rules of thumb: You (typically) directly call the method under test. You use spies when you need to observe something not directly accessible (like helpers.)  You fake or mock dependencies.